# Broken Snow Leopard Shell --how do I fix?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, bash, environment-variables

I think I managed to break my Snow Leopard shell, but I'm not sure.  Is there a way to reset all env variables to default?

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I was trying to install Sphinx4 from src.  I changed a whole bunch of env variables to use the specific java library, but in the process made some bad changes so now no java program runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close terminal and re-open a new one. Any environments variables you set in the last session will be gone.

If the problem persists, you probably edited `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`; edit them again and remove any changes (or if you want to get right back to the default OS X state, just remove them completely - a default OS X install has these files empty or non-existent).

Answer (score 1):

One of the following:

- Exit the shell and start it again.
- Log out and log in.
- **`. /etc/bash.bashrc`**
- **`. ~/.bashrc`**
- exec bash -i

The two that start with "dot" source your startup files which will reset *some* of your environment variables (but may make your `$PATH` variable longer - probably with no consequences).

Comment: Isn't it `~/.bashrc`, not `./bashrc`?